# Internet Sharing via router

Tags: networking, ubuntu, mac-osx, internet

Question:

How to setup Internet Sharing among two computers (one Mac 10.5.6, one Ubuntu 9.10) via a router?

Situation:

The Mac is using AirPort (wireless interface) to connect to router as 192.168.1.101.
The Ubuntu is using an ethernet cable to connect to router as 192.168.1.104.

Visual:

Mac ))))))  Router ======= Ubuntu

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Is the router connected directly to the internet via a cable/DSL modem, or is something else going on?  What make/model is the router?

Answer (score 2):

I like your visual. So, this is what you need:

```
Mac )))))) Router ======= Ubuntu
              +
              |
              +---- Modem (ADSL/Cable/etc)---- (INTERNET)
```

You will need to configure your router to use the modem for Internet connections and it should do the rest of it automagically. The exact settings would depend on how you get your internet and the settings of your ISP. You will need that information before you configure your router.